# Intermittent flickering in one of the three lights of ceiling fan

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have a Hampton Bay 5-blade ceiling fan with three candelabra lights. One of the lights flickers seemingly randomly whenever it is on. I replaced all the three candelabra lights with new LEDs and the problem persist. The flickering is not affected if I turn the fan on or increase fan speed. I am not sure if this is a problem with the circuit the fixture is connected to (unlikely), a problem with the fixture itself (cheap one so maybe?), a problem with the socket (given that it is the same one the flickers despite changing the bulb). I would appreciate any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this flickering light. Thanks!

Light fixture:
(https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Glendale-52-in-LED-Indoor-White-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-AG524-WH/300937526).

Comment: Have you complained to Home Depot ?

Comment: I am trying to gain some understanding of what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it always the same lamp socket that flickers? When two lamps are switched, does the lamp in the same socket still flicker? Also try an incandescent lamp in the socket that flickers.

If everything in that socket flickers, then it's very likely a loose connection. Check for:

- A wire nut in the fixture that has the wire partially inserted. Push the wire from that socket in farther, and twist the wire nut a bit tighter.
- The center contact in the socket might be bent flat. It can be gently pried up with a hook.
- The socket shell connector might be riveted loosely. A gentle tap with on the rivets, with the rivet back supported, should fix that.

However, some LED's are more prone to flicker than others. If the incandescent lamp works, but the LED flickers, try yet a *different* LED in that socket.

Answer (score 0):

I really suspect a bad connection internal to the fan. Have you tried an incandescent bulb? LED's seem to be a lot more finicky. If you bought from Home Depot, may want to see if they will exchange it.

Comment: yes I tried both LED and incandescent, issue persists.